# How to set default applications non-interactively (e.g. vlc as default for video)?

Tags: 12.10, bash

It's straightforward to set vlc as default using the GUI, but 
straightforward doesn't mean easy(I have to do the same thing over and over many times
each time I install a new system).
I just need a short command for this(e.g. set a gconf or dconf key).
Please no answers like right-click and select Properties.

Answer (score 4):

That information is stored in .local/share/applications/mimeapps.list, I save a copy of that file and copy it to new systems.

Comment: is there a better way of doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default mimetype handler with the `gvfs-mime` command. Unfortunately, you need to do this for each mimetype. There's no way I know to set it for all video at once.

```
gvfs-mime --set video/mp4 vlc.desktop
```

You could of course script that.

```
#!/bin/bash

MIMETYPES="video/x-flv video/mp4 video/mpeg video/ogg video/x-theora+ogg"

for i in $MIMETYPES; do
   gvfs-mime --set $i vlc.desktop
done
```

To makesure you get all the mimetypes that Totem is set to handle, you could parse it's desktop file for the MIMETYPES variable like:

```
MIMETYPES=`cat /usr/share/applications/totem.desktop | grep "MimeType" | cut -d '=' -f 2 | tr ";" " "`
```